# Passing multiple params in Redux Toolkit's createAsyncThunk

Tags: reactjs, redux-toolkit

I have the following code where I want to send **POST** request in with a data object and a history function. How can I pass the history param in the action creator? Thanks

**login action creator**

```
import { createAsyncThunk } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { client } from '../client';
import {User} from './userLoginSlice';


export const userLogin = createAsyncThunk('user/userLogin' , async (data: User, history: string,  thunkAPI)  => {
  try {
    const res = await client.post<User>('/User/Credentials/Login', data); 
    if(res.status === 200) history.push('/dashboard');
    return res.data;
  } catch (error) {
    return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue('Sorry! Something went wrong ):') ;
  }
});
```

**login slice**

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { userLogin } from './userLoginThunk';


export interface User{
 email: string;
 passowrd: string;
 rememberMe: boolean;
}


const initialState = {
  user:  {} as User,
  loading: false,
  error: ''
};

export const userLoginSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'user',
  initialState: initialState,
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder.addCase(userLogin.pending, (state) => {
      state.loading = true;
      state.error = '';
    });
    builder.addCase(userLogin.fulfilled, (state, { payload }) => {
      state.loading = false;
      state.user = payload;
    });
    builder.addCase(userLogin.rejected, (state, { payload }) => {
      state.loading = false;
      state.error = String(payload);
    });
  }
});

export const userLoginReducer = userLoginSlice.reducer;
```

**Using the action creator in a component**

```
import { Form, Input, Checkbox } from 'antd';
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

import { ConfirmBtn } from '../small-components/ActionBtns';
import { useAppDispatch } from '../../custom-hooks/reduxCustomHooks';
import {userLogin } from 'src/redux/user-login/userLoginThunk';
import {User} from '../../redux/user-login/userLoginSlice';
import '../../sass/light-theme/user-login.scss';

export const UserLogin = () => {
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch();
  const history = useHistory();

  const onFinish = (values: User) => {
    dispatch(userLogin(values, history));
  };
  return (
   
   <Form></Form>  
  );
};
```

It's throwing the error which says that the userLogin expects 1 arguments but got 2. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you pass arguments to createAsyncThunk in redux toolkit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64742747/how-do-you-pass-arguments-to-createasyncthunk-in-redux-toolkit)

Comment: i have a similar problem, because i have a topics.service.js, inside i have a function to make a post to backend, and i need to pass the token. And i can not pass the token from the component to the function in the dispatch, i receive a 'extra: {....a lot o things..}'

Answer (score 3):

A thunk only [accepts one parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64742747/3170628), so you would have to provide an object containing both your values and the history object.

In your case, you could also use the the [`unwrap()` function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64742747/3170628) (https://stackoverflow.com/a/67876542/3170628) so you don't have to provide the `history` object to your thunk:

```
const onFinish = async (values: User) => {
  try {
    await dispatch(userLogin(values)).unwrap();
    history.push('/dashboard');
  } catch (error) {
    ...
  }
};
```