# How to pass argument when using createAsyncThunk?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk, redux-toolkit

Checked this, but pass one argument and destructing did not help.

[How do you pass arguments to createAsyncThunk in redux toolkit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64742747/how-do-you-pass-arguments-to-createasyncthunk-in-redux-toolkit)

Have this:

```js
export const login = createAsyncThunk("users/login", async (user, params) => {
  const { name, data } = params;
  const { userContext } = await axios({
    method: "post",
    url: `loginEmail`,
    data: data,
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
  });
  return userContext;
});
```

and got this error:

```
ERROR in src/components/CreatePost.tsx:142:25

TS2554: Expected 0 arguments, but got 1.
    140 |               onClick={() => {
    141 |                 dispatch(
  > 142 |                   login({
        |                         ^
  > 143 |                     email: "j",
        | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  > 144 |                     password: "S",
        | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  > 145 |                   })
        | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    146 |                 );
    147 |               }}
```

When calling:

```js
dispatch(
  login({
    email: "janoech",
    password: "xxx",
  }))
```

importing here:

```
import { login } from "../slices/User";
```

and the slice:

```js
const userSlice = createSlice({
  name: "user",
  initialState: {
    userContext: null,
  },
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder.addCase(getUser.fulfilled, (state, payload) => {
      state.userContext = payload;
    });
    builder.addCase(logout.fulfilled, (state, payload) => {
      state.userContext = null;
    });
    builder.addCase(login.fulfilled, (state, { payload }) => {
      state.userContext = payload;
    });
  },
});

export default userSlice.reducer;
```

Comment: You are still destructuring the second argument here, not the first as you should.

Comment: Even if I destruct the first argument, got the same error. Do you know why?

Comment: Ah, you are using TypeScript. You have to give the parameter a type.